# How to navigate all the children Tags in a XML Structure

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I have the following xml :

```
   <VON>
        <OverXP name="UML1"  >
            <Property name="actor1" value="1"  />
            <OverXP name="UML2"  >
                <Property name="actor2" value="2"  />      
            </OverXP>  
        </OverXP>
    </VON>
```

I need to each all attributes , as a tree : the result should looks like :

level1: actor1 = 1 level2: actor2 = 2

my code :

```
XPathNavigator nav;
XPathDocument docNav;
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
String strExpression;
// Open the XML.
docNav = new XPathDocument(@"C:\uml.xml");
 // Create a navigator to query with XPath.
 nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
strExpression = "//OverXP//*";
NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);
```

but does not work !

Comment: I don't see `Overview` element in XML...

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for a string node on an attribute value in `@name/string()`, which is incorrect and cannot be done. In XPATH, you don't need to explicitly state the type like in object oriented code, there are only result values whose types you will handle in the C# layer. string() is used to return just the character values of your desired result.

So, use something more like `//OverXP [@name= 'UML2']`

But from the looks of your desired result, you may want to use `contains()` like so:
`//OverXP[contains(@name, 'UML')]` but this will give you some of the results more than once, so you can append `[1]` to the query, or refine it to be more specific to what you'd like to see.

Comment: I need to get all children

Comment: This gets you all the children, have you tried it? I'm not too sure what result you mean to get back by `level1: actor1 = 1 level2: actor2 = 2`, XPath returns a snippet of the XML or values within. If you could provide an example of the XML portion you're after, I can update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that uses **LINQ query syntax** that I believe will get the results that you want:

```cs
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);

var query =
    from property in
        document.Descendants("OverXP").Elements("Property")
    select new
    {
        Level = property.Ancestors().Count() - 1,
        Actor = (string)property.Attribute("name"),
        Value = (string)property.Attribute("value")
    };
```

I have incorporated your sample data and this query into a demonstration program. Please see below for the formatted output from the demonstration program followed by the program itself.

**Expected Output**

```
[Level 1] => [actor1 = 1]
[Level 2] => [actor2 = 2]
```

**Demonstration Program**

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class LinqToXmlDemo
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xmlContent = GetXml();
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);

        var query =
            from property in
                document.Descendants("OverXP").Elements("Property")
            select new
            {
                Level = property.Ancestors().Count() - 1,
                Actor = (string)property.Attribute("name"),
                Value = (string)property.Attribute("value")
            };

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[Level {0}] => [{1} = {2}]",
                              item.Level, item.Actor, item.Value);
        }
    }

    static string GetXml()
    {
        return
            @"<VON>
                <OverXP name='UML1'>
                    <Property name='actor1' value='1' />
                    <OverXP name='UML2'>
                        <Property name='actor2' value='2' />
                    </OverXP>
                </OverXP>
              </VON>";
    }
}
```